# Socket.io (1.x) .to(room) not working, but works without

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm building a simple messaging server and it works perfect using the `socket.broadcast.emit()` however if you use the `socket.broadcast.in(room).emit()` it dose not connect up. I've include the server code and client code below.

server

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;

var room;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

// When a new connection is launched
io.on('connection', function(socket){

  console.log('user connected: '+socket.id);

  //========== INIT connection =========
  // once a client has connected, we expect to get a ping from them saying what room
  // they want to join
  socket.on('room', function(data) {
    room = data;

    socket.join(room);

    console.log('  + User: '+socket.id+' - joined Room: ['+room+']');
    console.log('  + User: '+socket.id+' - has Rooms: ['+socket.rooms+']');

    // Display all sockets connected to room
    inRoom(room);
  });

 //======== Delegates messages ========
 socket.on('message_send', function(data){

    var JSONdata  = JSON.parse(data);
    var room_l    = JSONdata.chat_id;
    var msg       = JSONdata.message;

    console.log('Room: ' + room_l + ' - Message: ' + msg);

    // Send message
    //io.emit('message_received', msg);
    //socket.broadcast.emit('message_received', msg);
    io.in('TZRfM7V5HH').emit('message_recieved', msg);
    //io.to(room_l).emit('message_received', msg);

    // Save message to parse
    parseSAVE(data);
  });
});
```

Client

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
  var msg = $('#m').val();

  var room = 'TZRfM7V5HH';

  $( document ).ready(function() {
    socket.emit('room',room);
    socket.emit('message_send', '{"chat_id":"'+room+'","message":"yoyoyo shits to hype"}');
  });

  $('form').submit(function(){
    $msg = $('#m').val();
    socket.emit('message_send', '{"chat_id":"'+room+'","message":"'+$msg+'"}');
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text($msg));
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('message_received', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
```

I have been playing around with this all week and I cant seem to figure out whats wrong with my implementation, any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, first, `socket.boradcast.in(room).emit()` is a typo

Comment: my fault in the text but in the actual code its not.

Comment: Sounds good. One suggestion - you shouldn't have to pass strings around and manually parse JSON messages. If you sent around actual JavaScript object literals, the parsing should automatically happen with Socket.io. This isn't a problem, I just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: I have a very similar app with very similar logic, except I use `io.to(ROOM_ID).emit(MESSAGE_TYPE, DATA);`. Does that help/change anything?

Comment: Its communicating with an IOS app primarily so thats the reason we have the JSON objects, and I will try with that change thanks. Will update if it works or not.

Comment: No doesn't seem to make a difference, but that line does seem to be the problem as the event itself (message_send) is being called.